# Dealing with NoHostAvailableException with phantom DSL

Tags: scala, cassandra, datastax-java-driver, phantom-dsl

When trying to insert several thousand records at once into a remote Cassandra db, I reproducibly run into timeouts (with 5 to 6 thousand elements on a slow connection)

error:

```
All host(s) tried for query failed (tried: /...:9042
(com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.OperationTimedOutException: [/...]
Timed out waiting for server response))
com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.NoHostAvailableException: 
All host(s) tried for query failed (tried: /...:9042
(com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.OperationTimedOutException: [/...]
Timed out waiting for server response))
```

the model:

```
class RecordModel extends CassandraTable[ConcreteRecordModel, Record] {

  object id extends StringColumn(this) with PartitionKey[String]

...
abstract class ConcreteRecordModel extends RecordModel 
    with RootConnector with ResultSetFutureHelper {

def store(rec: Record): Future[ResultSet] = 
    insert.value(_.id, rec.id).value(...).future()

def store(recs: List[Record]): Future[List[ResultSet]] = Future.traverse(recs)(store)
```

the connector:

```
val connector = ContactPoints(hosts).withClusterBuilder(
  _.withCredentials(
    config.getString("username"),
    config.getString("password")
  ).withPoolingOptions(
    new PoolingOptions().setCoreConnectionsPerHost(HostDistance.LOCAL, 4)
      .setMaxConnectionsPerHost(HostDistance.LOCAL, 10)
      .setCoreConnectionsPerHost(HostDistance.REMOTE, 2)
      .setMaxConnectionsPerHost(HostDistance.REMOTE, 4)
      .setMaxRequestsPerConnection(HostDistance.LOCAL, 32768)
      .setMaxRequestsPerConnection(HostDistance.REMOTE, 2000)
      .setPoolTimeoutMillis(10000)
  )
).keySpace(keyspace)
```

I have tried tweaking the pooling options, separately and together. But even doubling all of the `REMOTE` settings did not change the timeout noticeably

current workaround, which I would like to avoid - splitting the list into batches and wait for completion of each:

```
def store(recs: List[Record]): Future[List[ResultSet]] = {
  val rs: Iterator[List[ResultSet]] = recs.grouped(1000) map { slice =>
    Await.result(Future.traverse(slice)(store), 100 seconds)
  }
  Future.successful(rs.to[List].flatten)
}
```

What would be a good way to handle this issue?

Thank you

**EDIT**

The errors do suggest failing/overloaded cluster, but I suspect network plays a major role here. The numbers provided above are from a remote machine. They are MUCH higher, when the same C* is fed from a machine in the same datacenter. Another suspicious detail is that feeding the same C* instance with [quill](https://github.com/getquill/quill) does not encounter any timeout issues, remote or not.

What I really dislike about throttling is that the batch sizes are random and static, while they should be adaptible.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you're hitting the limits of your cluster. If you want to avoid timeouts you will need to add more capacity to be able to handle the load. If you want to just do burst writes you should throttle them (as you are doing), as sending too many queries to too few nodes will inhibit performance. You can also increase the timeouts on the server side (read_request_timeout_in_ms, write_request_timeout_in_ms, request_timeout_in_ms) if you want to wait until you can write however this is not advisable as you will not give Cassandra any time to recover and likely cause large amounts of ParNew GC.

Comment: IIUC you are suggesting that the way to go would be adding more machines? This can be done, but I am still wondering about the low number of accepted requests. Have added some details above, perhaps you have an idea. Could you please share some details on a reasonable retry strategy? What would be a reasonable time for the cluster to recover. Have experimented backing off with increasing timeouts, but sometimes even retrying after 30sec seems to be to early.

Comment: When using quill are you performing the same queries? These exceptions definitely occur from timeouts client side but because the cluster is taking too long to respond with the results. Are you seeing lots of GC in the logs on the servers? If the cluster doesn't appear to be under much load CPU/IO-wise then you could also increase the read timeout client side
http://docs.datastax.com/en/drivers/java/2.1/com/datastax/driver/core/SocketOptions.html#setReadTimeoutMillis-int-